# combine "count" and "for_each" is not possible

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is my code source

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  count               = var.s3_create[1] ? 1 : 0 
  depends_on          = [aws_s3_bucket.bucket_backup]
  for_each            = local.buckets_and_folders 
    bucket            = each.value.bucket_backup
    key               = format("%s/", each.value.folder)
  force_destroy       = true
}
```

In other words, I'm traying to create object `aws_s3_bucket_object` depends on variable `s3_create` ... create if true else not create.

Issue: I am not able to use the combination of both the below syntax in creating the terraform resource and I'm geeting :

```
Error: Invalid combination of "count" and "for_each"
│
│   on ..\s3\resources.tf line 51, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object":
│   51:   for_each            = local.buckets_and_folders
│
│ The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only one should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be created.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both count and for_each apply to the whole block. Indenting lines underneath a for_each doesn't impact anything but human readability.

Try using the ternary operator with a for_each instead of a count. If the value is false, return an empty set.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  for_each       = var.s3_create[1] ? tomap({local.buckets_and_folders}) : {}
  bucket         = each.value.bucket_backup
  key            = format("%s/", each.value.folder)
  depends_on     = [aws_s3_bucket.bucket_backup]
  force_destroy  = true
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried but it's giving this error : `Error: Inconsistent conditional result types
│
│   on ..\dentinnov-infra\modules\storage\s3\resources.tf line 50, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object":
│   50:   for_each       = var.s3_create[1] ? local.buckets_and_folders : toset([])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.buckets_and_folders is object with 3 attributes
│     │ var.s3_create[1] is false
│
│ The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are object and set of dynamic, respectively.`

Comment: Ah. If `buckets_and_folders` is an object, you need to convert it to a type that's easier to compare. I've updated the answer to change both to maps.

Comment: Yeh it better now but still giving this error :  `│ Error: Missing key/value separator
│
│   on ..\dentinnov-infra\modules\storage\s3\resources.tf line 49, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object":
│   49:   for_each       = var.s3_create[1] ? tomap({local.buckets_and_folders}) : tomap({})
│
│ Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.`

Comment: Apologies! Remove the `tomap({})` and replace with `{}`

Comment: Hello Dan, thanks a lot for your helping. So, it was worked  as per your suggestion :   `resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  for_each       = var.s3_create[1] ? local.buckets_and_folders : {}
  bucket         = each.value.bucket_backup
  key            = format("%s/", each.value.folder)
  depends_on     = [aws_s3_bucket.bucket_backup]
  force_destroy  = true  
}`

Answer (score 2):

The rule for `for_each` is that you should assign it a map or set that has the same number of elements as the number of instances you want to declare.

Thinking about your goal from that standpoint, the solution will involve making your map be empty in situations where you want to declare no instances. The typical way to filter elements from a collection is to write [a `for` expression] with [an `if` clause](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#filtering-elements).

From what you shared in your example I can't tell if `local.buckets_and_folders` is a map or a set of strings, so I'll show examples for both...

If it's a map:

```
  for_each = tomap({
    for k, v in local.buckets_and_folders : k => v
    if var.s3_create[1]
  })
```

If it's a set:

```
  for_each = toset([
    for v in local.buckets_and_folders : v
    if var.s3_create[1]
  ])
```

In both cases the `if` clause means that the result will be an empty collection if `var.s3_create[1]` is false.

There may be other ways to design your module so that the input and the derived expressions can be simpler, but working within the relatively limited examples you shared the above is the most direct answer to your question. If you'd like to talk about possible ways to simplify this, you could ask a new question on Stack Overflow and include a fuller example of your current code and the underlying requirements this module is intended to meet.